# How to find the characteristic number of a given integral equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

How to find the characteristic number of the following integral equation?
$$y(x)= \lambda \int_{0}^{1} (3x-2)ty(t)dt$$

Comment: It has NO characteristic number

Answer (score 3):

$y(x)=\lambda (3x-2)C$ where , $\displaystyle C=\int_0^1ty(t)\,dt$. Then , $$C=\int_0^1t\lambda  C(3t-2)\,dt=\lambda C(1-1)=0.$$Then , $y=0$ is the only trivial solution and so the equation has NO characteristic number.

Comment: **Why** is $y(x)$ a constant multiple of $(3x-2)$?

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Alvarez) Because the integration is on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you @ S.Panja. if C is non zero then how to find the characteristic number. If you have any ref. bk or meterial related to this question pls give me....

Comment: @DeepaRavi, I guess searching for solution to Fredholm integral equations with separable kernal will give you some idea about it. (I'm no expert in it; even I learned it last day digging in those lines). Also, I found [this](http://gauravtiwari.org/portfolio/elements-of-integral-equations/) PDF quite useful in getting a basic idea about IEs.

Comment: yes... thank u @S.panja. and Jesse P Francis.

Comment: What is actually meant by the characteristic number of an integral equation?

Comment: Also, for it to have a non-zero characteristic number, how can we tweak the given statement?